# BEM. How to deal with label for/id?

Tags: input, label, accessibility, bem

As far as I know, BEM does not use elements id at all. But how to deal in this case with the label for/id combined with inputs? If I do not use id, people who're using screen readers will not get that this label is for that input. Am I right?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

BEM suggests avoiding `id` for css selectors. It's perfectly valid to use `id` for A11y and usability.

```
<form class="form" method="post" action="">
    <label for="email" class="form__label">Email</label>
    <input type="email" id="email" class="form__control"/>
</form>
```

In the example above we are styling the input as an Element of the `form` block with the `form__control` class.

Also you can not use aria attributes without `id` for pointers to descriptive elements.

```
<div role="application" aria-labelledby="calendar" aria-describedby="info">
    <h1 id="calendar">Calendar</h1>
    <p id="info">
        This calendar shows the game schedule for the Boston Red Sox.
    </p>
    <div role="grid">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

Example taken from: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Techniques/Using_the_aria-describedby_attribute

Comment: Do you mean that BEM avoiding id for selector only, but may use it in markup?

Comment: @andrey.shedko Yes, of course :) You can not make accessible applications without the use of `id` attribute. Even the guys that created BEM are using ids: https://yandex.com/ Inspect their code :)